# What is a high brilliance X-Ray and how is one created

Tags: radiation, x-rays

I just found this term being used in a Stanford Engineering year in review 2013-2014 "X-rays illuminate path to more efficient fuel cells" that cited this [work](http://news.stanford.edu/pr/2014/pr-ions-fuel-cells-070914.html). Never heard the term before and I came looking here and found no questions or answers on the subject. Does anybody know how these are created and are they purely man made or can they be found in nature as well.

I found a hit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_light_source#Brilliance), but it defines the measure, which is ok, but then the question becomes what range of values would qualify a particular beam as being brilliant? They also mention that brilliance is already captured by the idea of intensity. Is that true?

Comment: That's the new use of SLAC's (https://www.google.com/search?q=slac&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1960&bih=759&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=F0KnVPnHFYTZoASUyICoCQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAw) 2 mile long linear accelerator. It has basically outlived its usefulness as a high energy research facility and is now being used as a high brightness x-ray source that can produce extremely quick snapshots of systems at the atomic scale. It's an ultrabright x-ray flashlight, if you want. Of course, most samples are probably gone after the flash... :-) Look at their website for details: https://www6.slac.stanford.edu/

Comment: I have been looking for a comprehensive answer to what they are calling "high brilliance" and I found their Q&A for users, which tries to answer the basic question of "So what comes out of the tube mate?" in a rather down to earth way (which for a high energy physics experiment is a pleasant experience!). Take a look and let me know if you need some interpretation: https://portal.slac.stanford.edu/sites/lclscore_public/Lists/LCLS_FAQ/FAQ.aspx

Comment: Oops... I actually directed you to the wrong facility. After reading the bottom of the news article it seems that the research was done by Standford folks but using Berkeley's light source: http://www-als.lbl.gov/. The machine parameters are here:  http://www-als.lbl.gov/index.php/beamlines/photon-source-parameters.html.